# anything wrong with passing these variables in java

Tags: java

Ambitious newbie here. Help wanted please.

On trying to connect to a MySQL database and show results to a `JTable`, my query accepts parameters from some variables thus:

```
private String conv = "c_name as name,gender";
private String varYear;

[later when a JButton makes a click action, it tries to connect and display the results]

 try{
    varYear = yearTF.getText();

    //troubleshooting my varYear variable with this next dialog shows that the varYear variable gets the appropriate text that is entered into the yearTF textfield 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, varYear);

    String sql = "SELECT  "+conv+" FROM  pTable WHERE  date LIKE  '%"+varMonth+"%' AND  date LIKE  '%"+varYear+"%' ";

    //now troubleshooting my statement with this next dialog shows that the varYear variable is null 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sql);


    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    Table_stats.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Question 1: What did the 'String sql = ...' do to the varYear that was first of all 2014 (for example) to become null?

Question 2: How can I have my varYear to contain 2014 and not the null it has become?

// varMonth suffers the same problem but I just asked for varYear hoping it'll shoot the two birds.
Thanks.

Comment: This may cause a SQL Injection.  You should look it up before you deploy to production.

Comment: You sure you're showing us all the code? varYear can't change from one line to the other in the code you posted.

Comment: [Bobby Tables' mom](http://xkcd.com/327/) would like to have a word with you.